# Deserializing recursive JSON to C# with JSON.NET

Tags: c#, json, recursion, json.net, deserialization

We're using the [jQuery Querybuilder plugin](http://mistic100.github.io/jQuery-QueryBuilder/) to create a dynamic filtering component for the users of our application:

[image]

One of the most interesting features is the ability the serialization of a filter set, something like this:

```
{
 "condition": "AND",
  "rules": [
  {
   "id": "filterGroup1",
   "field": "filterGroup1",
   "type": "string",
   "input": "select",
   "operator": "contains",
   "value": "1"
 },
 {
   "id": "filterGroup2",
   "field": "filterGroup2",
   "type": "string",
   "input": "select",
   "operator": "contains",
   "value": "3"
 },
 {
   "condition": "OR",
   "rules": [
     {
      "id": "filterGroup1",
      "field": "filterGroup1",
      "type": "string",
      "input": "select",
      "operator": "contains",
      "value": "1"
    }
  ]
}
]
}
```

As you may notice, the data is recursive: the third node has the same type as the root node. This is giving me issues when deserializing this to the server. Currently I have this:

```
public class QueryBuilderFilter
{       
    public string Condition { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Rule> Rules { get; set; }
}

 public class Rule
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Field { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Input { get; set; }
    public string Operator { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<QueryBuilderFilter> Filters { get; set; }
}
```

Here's what I call:

```
 JsonSerializerSettings jsonSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All,
            TypeNameAssemblyFormat = FormatterAssemblyStyle.Full,
            Error = (sender, eventArgs) =>
            {
                eventArgs.ErrorContext.Handled = true;
            }
        };

QueryBuilderFilter deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<QueryBuilderFilter>(filtering, jsonSettings );
```

Everything until the IEnumerable property goes perfectly, meaning all data except this property are hydrated. However, the third node returns null:

[image]

This node should correspond to the child item but I can't figure out a proper or clean way to do this. Not using a type and manually parsing could be an option but that sounds like a very intensive and expensive solution whereas I believe there should be easier solutions. It wouldn't be a real problem if I knew the amount of items up front, but the control allows for unlimited query building, so I need to be able to process this dynamically.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `Rule` needs condition and Rules on it and then [you get this](http://i.imgur.com/xnXTUKG.jpg)

Comment: @Plutonix that's correct. Guillaume has the same solution, and because he was earlier I gave him the credit for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your JSON, can you try with this model :

```
public class Rule
{
  public string Id { get; set; }
  public string Field { get; set; }
  public string Type { get; set; }
  public string Input { get; set; }
  public string Operator { get; set; }
  public string Value { get; set; }
  public string Condition { get; set; }
  public IEnumerable<Rule> Rules { get; set; }
}
```

And this your JSON model translated in C# :

```
var filter = new Rule
{
    Condition = "AND",
    Rules = new List<Rule> {
        new Rule 
        {
            Id = "filterGroup1",
            Field = "filterGroup1",
            Type = "string",
            Input = "select",
            Operator = "contains",
            Value = "1"
        },
        new Rule 
        {
            Id = "filterGroup2",
            Field = "filterGroup2",
            Type = "string",
            Input = "select",
            Operator = "contains",
            Value = "3"
        },
        new Rule
        {
            Condition = "OR",
            Rules = new List<Rule> {
                new Rule 
                {
                    Id = "filterGroup1",
                    Field = "filterGroup1",
                    Type = "string",
                    Input = "select",
                    Operator = "contains",
                    Value = "1"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I was a bit sceptical about this solution at first, but it actually makes sense if you think about it.

Comment: Thanks. The initial problem was the fact that you store 2 differents structures in rules array. It's valid for a JSON model but not for a strong-typed C# structure.